# How can I get javascript output to show in VS Studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I am a complete beginner and so am just playing around with writing some code. I can get output to show in browser web developer tools, but nothing shows up (even errors) in the output panel on VSS. From what I've seen (videos), when I save my file, the the output should automatically show in the output panel. I'm missing something but don't know what. I am using Visual Studio Code version 1.85.2
[screenshot of code in program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtidM.png)

I have seen a lot of suggestions of saving, or right click and click 'run'. It doesn't show up 'run' for me on the right click menu but I have clicked the green play icon in the top left corner. It switched my view over from 'output' to 'terminal' and then prints my local file path.

Another solution suggested going into setting and enabling 'Run in terminal', but that option wasn't there that I could see.

I have the extensions 'live server' and 'prettier' installed.

Thanks

Comment: The output pane of VS will not show JS output, so this is expected behaviour. If you want to see the output you would need to actually execute the JS code within a web browser and look at the console in Devtools.

Comment: Instead of running your code in the browser, you can also run it with Node.js from within VSCode. Open the terminal in VSCode and run `node index.js`. Do be aware that Node is limited in what it can run: anything DOM related won't work as Node has different API's compared to the browsers that we use.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work. So I can't make it output without typing that code?

Comment: Not by default. But I'm sure there is an extension which will allow you to run it on save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the Code to see any output, I suggest you use Node.js to do this. Node.js is a runtime for JavaScript and lets you execute it outside of the Browser. You can download it here and read the doc. https://nodejs.org/en

To go into more detail as suggested by **gyohza**.

As **Rory McCrossan** already explained in his comment:
The output pane of VS will not show JS output, so this is expected behaviour.

This is because you can't just run JS code in VS. You first need a runtime environment for JavaScript to run.
There are a couple of ways to run your JS code, as I suggested earlier, Node.js is a very common way to run JS code and has a very rich documentation and many tutorials.

If you choose Node.js, you can run your code in your terminal inside VS or elsewhere:

```
node filename.js
```

You then can see the output of your JS code in the terminal.

Hers is a little example, i used Visual Studio Code and Node.js.

[image: A example screenshot]

As mentioned before, if you want to know how to install Node.js, you can go to [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/learn/getting-started/how-to-install-nodejs) and read the docs.

Comment: If you reread the question and its comments, you'll realize that the OP's main problem is that they're confusing the purpose of the **Output** tab. Your suggestion is still valid, though, but you didn't provide any examples whatsoever. I would suggest you break it down in steps, preferrably with a screenshot so there's no confusion where the code output will be. Just for the record, I wasn't the one to downvote you, but your answer needs improvement - and that is perfectly okay, it usually takes a few peer reviews until we familiarize with the community's standards. I recommend you start by re

Comment: (Sorry, my message got cropped for some reason, I had linked to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)). I get you and I don't want you to shy away from answering other questions. You can still edit it and we can even it out (as I said, your suggestion _is_ valid, I'll upvote you myself if the answer is up to standard). Look around, check other upvoted answers elsewhere and reflect on how yours can be improved. Just so you know, when someone downvotes your answer, they actually **lose a reputation point** in doing so - so it's usually not simply out of spite.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have edited my answer and provided more information.

Answer (score 0):

Running it with Node.js from within VSCode did the trick. Thank you everyone- I appreciate all the answers.

Comment: Hello! That's essentially what was suggested by @Vincent. Would you mind upvoting and selecting their answer as the accepted answer if it solves the problem you described? I would generally just recommend upvoting good answers instead of producing duplicates - besides, [your answer could use a little improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I did try but as I don't have enough reputation it doesn't let me. And I just discovered the 'accept answer' button 